# Manage Circular SeekBar throughout the app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an app that is used to stream songs online. I am able to play the song on clicking on it.

The problem with me is that I have a CircularSeekBar in all the Activities and I need to manage it on all the screens. If a song is played from any activity CircularSeekBar should be visible on all the screens. What I am able to do is When a song is played I am able to show the seekbar on that particular activity but not able to manage that seekbar on any other activity.

Below is the sample of one of my xml files:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 </LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/seek_bar_layout"></include>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please let me know how to manage that Seekbar on all the Activities.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manage activity view when other is visible.

You can solve it by any `boolean` flag (for example: `isSongPlaying = false`). When you start playing your song set it to `true`. In each activity in onResume check that flag and show / hide your `SeekBar`.

Try to avoid using `public static` and use any other way.

---

### EDIT:

According to your comments i created very simple example how you can solve your problem using service. Remember this code need much improvements.

**SongService**

```
public class SongService extends Service {

    ActivityManager activityManager;
    IBinder iBinder;
    boolean playingSong = false;
    Worker worker;

    public SongService() {
        iBinder = new MyBinder();
    }

    private void playSong(String path) {
        if(worker != null) {
            worker.cancel(true);
        }
        worker = new Worker();
        worker.execute();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return iBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private class Worker extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            playingSong = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 100; i > -1; i--) {
                publishProgress(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100l);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if (activityManager != null) {
                activityManager.publishProgress(values[0]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            playingSong = false;
            activityManager.onSongFinish();
        }
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {

        public SongService getSongService() {
            return SongService.this;
        }

        public void BindView(ActivityManager activityManager) {
            SongService.this.activityManager = activityManager;
        }

        public void playSong(String path) {
            SongService.this.playSong(path);
        }

        public boolean isPlayingSong() {
            return playingSong;
        }
    }

    public interface ActivityManager {
        void publishProgress(int progress);

        void onSongFinish();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ServiceConnection, SongService.ActivityManager {

    TextView progress;
    Button play;
    Button next;
    SongService.MyBinder myBinder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(myBinder != null) {
                    //Your path to song
                    myBinder.playSong("");
                    play.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });


        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SongService.class);
        bindService(mIntent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        unbindService(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        if(service instanceof SongService.MyBinder) {
            myBinder = (SongService.MyBinder) service;
            myBinder.BindView(this);

            if (myBinder.isPlayingSong()) {
                play.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        myBinder = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void publishProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress.setText("Progress: " + progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSongFinish() {
        play.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity2**

This activity class looks exacly the same like MainActivity but have different layout file.

**MainActivity - Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aszymanski2.serviceanddelegatepatternexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
        android:text="SecondActivity"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity2 - Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aszymanski2.serviceanddelegatepatternexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Artur,
I am using a boolean but how will I access the view of the previous activity. I am able to make the saeekbar visible but the seekbar progress is not happening and If I click on that seekbar in another activity how will I change the icon in the previous activity.

Comment: @Arpit You have to change your logic i think. If i correctly understand activity plays the song right? in this case move this functionality to an service, and use delegate pattern. Every time when you start other activity bind this activity and your service. That solution gives you possibility to manage currently attached (visible) activity by your service.

Comment: Yes Activity Plays the song. But I have never used a Service, how can I manage it with Service ? I have played a song in Activity "A" and now I am in Activity "B". Can I control the icon in Activity A from Activity B ?

Comment: @Arpit Ok, you have to read about `Services` and `Delegate Pattern` currently i don't have access to IDE and can't create full example.

Comment: Ok, No Issues...Thanks for the help. whenever it is possible for you to create the example. Please do it and share it.

Comment: @Arpit ok check my answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113384/discussion-between-arpit-and-artur-szymanski).